# How to get the traffic data with Bing Map API in js

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I need to display the traffic condition in Toronto with Bing map. The purpose is to show the traffic condition when I select one route in a webpage. And the result should be text format. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Here is what I have so far;

```js
var map = null;

GetMap(43.643718, -79.388785, 10);

function GetMap(latitude, longitude, zoomLevel) {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
    credentials: "Bing code",
    zoom: zoomLevel
  });

  map.setView({
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude)
  });

  var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
    draggable: true
  });
  map.entities.push(pushpin);

  // Add a handler to the pushpin drag
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseup', DisplayLoc);

  map.entities.push(pushpin);

  map.setView({
    zoom: 10,
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(43.643718, -79.388785)
  })

  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', {
    callback: function() {
      trafficLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficLayer(map);
      // show the traffic Layer 
      trafficLayer.show();
    }
  });
}

function CallGetMap() {
  var latitude = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtLatitude').value);
  var longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtLongitude').value);
  var zoomLevel = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtZoomLevel').value);
  GetMap(latitude, longitude, zoomLevel);
}

function DisplayLoc(e) {
  if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {

    var pinLoc = e.target.getLocation();
    alert("The location of the pushpin is now " + pinLoc.latitude + ", " + pinLoc.longitude);

  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Latitude</span>
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Longitude</span>
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Zoom Level</span>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;" />
  <div style="float:left;margin-bottom:20px;">
    <input id="txtLatitude" type="text" />
    <input id="txtLongitude" type="text" />
    <input id="txtZoomLevel" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallGetMap();" />
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;" />
  <div id="myMap" style="position:relative; width:2000px; height:2000px;">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: _And the result should be text format_ could you explain this requirement better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample works, I made just two changes:

1- I've put a valid Bing Maps Key (with Application Url: http://stacksnippets.net/js) you can get one form [here](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/).

2- I've put a delay between the `loadModule` callback and the `trafficManager.show()`.

I could see in chrome console that the requests to traffic API were not properly sending the key, getting `401 (Unauthorized)` as response.

As you can see in the image below, the `&key={key}` seems incomplete. I guess this is a bug, or the initialization workflow is wrong. Whatever the delay fix the issue.

[image]

In contrast with the request sent with a delay, the key seems correct.

[image]

```js
var map = null;

GetMap(43.243718, -79.388785, 11);

function GetMap(latitude, longitude, zoomLevel) {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
    credentials: 'AsI529bayR--zjFnbPx2sl4yGScTrovaNNLsGPR9TxgcrUjFBpoqwKsxYtz9jPnS',
    zoom: zoomLevel
  });

  map.setView({
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude)
  });

  var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
    draggable: true
  });
  map.entities.push(pushpin);

  // Add a handler to the pushpin drag
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseup', DisplayLoc);

  map.entities.push(pushpin);
  
  map.setView({
    zoom: zoomLevel,
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude)
  })

  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', {
    callback: function() {
      trafficLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficLayer(map);
      // show the traffic Layer 
      setTimeout(function() {
        trafficLayer.show();
      }, 1000);

    }
  });
}

function CallGetMap() {
  var latitude = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtLatitude').value);
  var longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtLongitude').value);
  var zoomLevel = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtZoomLevel').value);
  GetMap(latitude, longitude, zoomLevel);
}

function DisplayLoc(e) {
  if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {

    var pinLoc = e.target.getLocation();
    alert("The location of the pushpin is now " + pinLoc.latitude + ", " + pinLoc.longitude);

  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Latitude</span>
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Longitude</span>
    <span style="margin-right:100px;">Zoom Level</span>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;" />
  <div style="float:left;margin-bottom:20px;">
    <input id="txtLatitude" type="text" />
    <input id="txtLongitude" type="text" />
    <input id="txtZoomLevel" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallGetMap();" />
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;" />
  <div id="myMap" style="position:relative; width:2000px; height:2000px;">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's faster than before. But, regarding with the data issue, could you tell me how to get the result?

Comment: Are you tried the Traffic Incidents API? I can't figure out what you want. what would be the output on the map

Comment: I tried just now, clicking the traffic layer does nothing.